# Display symfony website to be checked by clients before going to production + versioning

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

I know how to deploy the website on a specific domain name, but here I need to give online access to a project, which domain name is already used by the current version of the web site.

The goal is that the project will replace the website after being approved, so I need an online place to demonstrate it, other than the dev computer, for example: `https://example.com/project` so that both example.com and project have their own rules, etc.

It seems to me that's impossible this way, so I am wondering what are the best practices to do so?

Linked to this process, what are the best practices to give access for approval to updated versions, i.e. a modification is requested and done but displayed with a specific url: `https://example.org/v1.0/xxx` to test navigation, look and feel, etc. before being deployed on the production server, when approved.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my company we use to deploy first on a **staging**.

This pre-production is located on the same server as the production, at the subdomain `staging.example.com`, and is protected with a HTTP Basic Authentication on Apache.

The staging is linked to our git dev branch, so when we have to approve a new feature, we just have to deploy the branch, then when its approved we can merge into master and deploy to production.

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand it well. You deploy master to production server with all subdirectories (app, src, etc.) and then you deploy another git branch (with all subdirectories also) to another folder that is pointed out by the subdomain `staging.example.com` using the annotation host?

Comment: Yes that's it (but i'm not sure what you mean with 'using the annotation host'). It is really 2 isolated instances of our application, 2 folders, 2 databases.. One is for production and need to be clean, the second for staging is for client testing and validation phase.

Comment: Thanks! So, having the two applications in different folders, do you manage routes in the controller via http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html in order to separate access from production and staging or in another way?

Comment: Well we manage routes in xml for this project, but you can do it in controller with annotations, it's the same thing. Then to get routes we always generate it with SF, so the prefix `example.com` or `staging.example.com` is manage by SF, and you will not have any conflict. http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for your time and help, I will have try tomorrow

Comment: So, I have created one git branch "staging" that will serve between dev and master and this branch is pushed to a separate folder accessed via a subdomain protected via the HTTP Basic Authentication. The master branch will be pushed to the production site. Thanks a lot for having helped me on this subject!